# Как создать сайт для вывода информации из .txt?

Tags: arduino, веб-сайт, txt

Я создаю систему для учета времени прихода людей в помещение, у меня уже есть Arduino которая считывает карты людей с помощью rfid и отправляет эти данные в .txt. Но мне не хватает сайта который мог бы принимать эту информацию и выводить её на экран. С помощью чего это сделать?

Comment: Уточните, txt сохраняется на arduino или данные отсылаются по com/usb на комп, и сохраняются там?

Comment: Сначало в ком порт потом в .txt через программу Godetwino

Answer (score 0):

Так как задача сводится к отображению в web содержимого txt-файла, лежащего на компе с windows, я бы использовал сервер MicroApache и простенький скрипт на php, по аналогии с тем, как это сделано в проекте [ДокуВики на флешке](https://www.dokuwiki.org/ru:install:dokuwiki_on_a_stick).

Comment: То есть возможно сделать так что бы информация которая появлялась в файле появлялась и на сайте и удалилась через время? (В обычном формате в самом низу .txt появляется)

Comment: Если файл хоть как-то структурирован, например, "дата и время", "пробел", "текст", "конец строки", то его можно рассматривать как таблицу базы данных и выводить оттуда только нужные данные. Но это уже вопрос по php или другому языку программирования, на котором будет делаться обработчик.